# How to abort method in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue `@keyup` on input, this uses method with `axios` call:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Where are you from?" v-model="from" @keyup="getPlace">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="place in places">{{ place.name }}<li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            places: [],
            from: ''
        }
    },
    methods() {
        if(this.from.length <= 3) { this.places = []; return; }
        getPlace() {
            axios.get('/places?name='+this.from).then((res)=>{
                this.places = [];
                for(var i = 0; i<res.data.length; i++) {
                    this.places.push(res.data[i]);                  
                }
            }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Now this works but it has a big problem, each call it updates array of places but it is late, so the method is called and array has been returned to [] but after the response is back it is populating the array for each keyup (if you type fast)... I am switching from jquery front to this and I never ever had a problem with this :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer the "how to abort method", but you could use a different approach for your example: Fetching all places at the beginning (`mounted()`) and filter them based on the input in the frontend by using a computed property.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      places: [],
      from: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getPlaces();
  },
  computed: {
    placesList() {
      let result = []
      let places = this.places
      let from = this.from

      if (from !== '') {
        result = this.places.filter(element => {
          return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(from.toLowerCase())
        })
      } else {
        result = places
      }

      return result
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPlaces() {
      // axios call..
      this.places = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Germany"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "USA"
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "Spain"
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Where are you from?" v-model="from">
  <br /> input text: {{ from }}
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="place in placesList" :key="place.id">
      {{ place.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I was using this but I couldnt find good approach for SQL '%name%' so I went to directly SQL for that :D This is nice example I will use it :D